# How to turn off session state for a certain directory?

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a custom session provider that stores data in a DB, so fetching session state is not a cheap operation. I have also `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` in my `web.config`, so sessions are inicialized for every request to an image.

So, I am striving for turning off session state for directories with static resources. Unfortunately, setting `<sessionState mode="Off" />` for a folder does not work as this is application-level option.

I could handle this in the code of my custom session provider, but I am wondering if there is some cleaner, more declarative solution.

Edit: `<pages enableSessionState="false" />` does not seem to help as it is probably related to ASP.NET pages and controls only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, think about it as session is provided for the whole application, and you just can say at this folder i have and at that i don't, all you can do is to custom code the costly operation of your provider to not run according to certain conditions, place that correctly in your page life cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem trying to do WebServices with cookieless sessions.  I solved it with using a symbolic link.  Here are the steps:

1) Make your subdirectory its own application in IIS

2) put this in the subdirectory web.config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

3) Create a symbolic link to redirect BIN to your own BIN.  In my example the subdirectory was only 1 level below my main application.  So I did this command from the subdirectory:

```
mklink /D bin ..\bin
```

That's it.  It will load assemblies from your main BIN directory, and inherit all its other settings from your main application.

Comment: Wow, that's creative! :-) I'll try it as soon as possible.