# Disable session for a WCF REST service hosted inside an ASP.NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF REST service hosted inside an ASP.NET 3.5 website. The ASP.NET site uses SQL server provider for the sessions. I found that every time a request is sent to the WCF REST service. A session is created or updated to the [AspStateTempSessions] table.

This is causing performance issues (too many DB updates to the [AspStateTempSessions] table) and I am trying to figure out how to make WCF REST service request NOT to access that table.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! Please note that very unfortunately we are based on .NET 3.5 :(

**EDIT**, the web.config snippet

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="jsonpBinding">
                <jsonpMessageEncoding />
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
        <service name="MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Channel.Presenter.Api.Services.LocationPublicService" behaviorConfiguration="GenericServiceBehaviour">
            <endpoint address="json" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="jsonpBinding" contract="MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Common.Contracts.Api.Service.Rest.ILocationPublicServiceJsonP" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpointBehaviour" />
        </service>      
    </services>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="NewtonsoftWebHttpBehavior" type="MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Core.Extensions.Binding.JsonP.NewtonsoftWebHttpElement, MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e6046ce543c5d449" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
        <bindingElementExtensions>
            <add name="jsonpMessageEncoding" type="MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Core.Extensions.Binding.JsonpBindingExtension, MyCompany.Mccp.Commerce.Core" />
        </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RestEndpointBehaviour">
                <webHttp />
                <webHttpBehaviourWithFault />
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="RestEndpointBehaviourJson">
                <webHttp />
                <webHttpBehaviourWithFault />
                <NewtonsoftWebHttpBehavior />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="GenericServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Does the WCF service have it's own subfolder? My guess is disabling the session state (web.config) in that subfolder should work.

Comment: I think I am wrong in my assumption above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422198/how-to-turn-off-session-state-for-a-certain-directory

Comment: can you share the config file that applies to your service? also what's the attributes on your service contract